# How to install on client side when setup.exe and supported files kept in server in ADF?

Tags: oracle-adf

I developed an application using Oracle ADF in Jdev 11.1.1.5.0.
I deployed application in weblogic server and working fine.

I kept one setup.exe file and supported files in server.
Now I want the installation should be done on client machine while the page is loading itself.
Using servlet, how can we achieve this?

The installation(exection of setup.exe file) should be done automatically in client machine.

and what are the steps should I follow to accomplish this?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this automatically. The sandbox can't execute anything on the client side without a change of the policy. This change can't be done without the user on the client side.
What you can do is to ask the user to download the files and then execute the setup.exe after downloading.

However, I personally would not do this without knowing what the exe is doing on my pc. A web application normally don't need to be installed on a client pc.

Timo